# Check if username has 4 consecutive letters from name - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to build a registration form where the user has to enter in their username along with their name. In order to add security and follow privacy requirements I need to not allow users to enter in their name as their username. (4 consecutive letters within the name as a minimum).

For example 1-

Name = John Doe

Username = JohnUser or NdoeUser

For example 2-

Name - Johnny English

Username - JohnEng123 or English321 or yeng321

The above examples should prompt an error. The first one has John as the 4 consecutive letters and the second has the last characters of the first name and the surname as the 4 consecutive letters.

I would like to know if this is possible via regex or if I have to loop through each character or set of 4 characters and check if its present in the username.

Comment: Why do you not want users to have their name in `Username`?

Comment: The example would have less ambiguity if you chose a longer name, like Johnny for example.

Comment: Usernames are mostly public information, there's no use to limit the format. Rather check the password fullfills the security criteria.

Comment: Its a requirement from the site as this site hold information of a specific user group where  privacy is of the utmost importance. We already have password that require a certain checklist but this has also come up and I would like to know if there is a better way rather than going character by character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a pattern of the `name` and get a regular expression for a letter and following three letters, like

```
/J(?=ohn)|o(?=hnD)|h(?=nDo)|n(?=Doe)/i
```

and return the negated result of the check.

```js
function check(name, login) {
    let pattern = [];
    name = name.replace(/\s+/, '');    
    for (let i = 0, l = name.length - 3; i < l; i++) {
        pattern.push(`${name[i]}(?=${name.slice(i + 1, i + 4)})`);
    }

    return !new RegExp(pattern.join('|'), 'i').test(login);
}

console.log(check('John Doe', 'JohnUser'));
console.log(check('John Doe', 'NdoeUser'));
console.log(check('Johnny English', 'JohnEng123'));
console.log(check('Johnny English', 'English321'));
console.log(check('Johnny English', 'yeng321'));
console.log(check('foo bar', 'abcdefg'));
```

Comment: ah thank you.. I will give this a go and let you know how everything goes :) .. much appreciated.